# Is the size already updated in OnResize()?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a PlotBox control, which inherits from a PictureBox. Every time the control changes its size, I want to redraw the plot. If I do something like that:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResize(e);
    Replot();        
}
private void Replot()
{
    //logic goes here, for example:
    int width = Size.Width; 
    int height = Size.Height;
}
```

Will the `width` and `height` variables hold the new control size? Are there any additional problems I should have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

The size will already have been updated by the time your `Replot()` method is called.